# avoid to split full name from string in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

I have a string composed from some values separated by comma; this string contains also, a full name (firstName, lastName). I need to make an array that contains all values from string, but also the full name (not splited). How could I avoid spliting the full name? Thanks!

```
var string = "Joe, Doe,Author,Title,Mary, Doe",
    array = string.split(",");
```

results in:

```
 ["Joe", " Doe", "Author", "Title", "Mary", " Doe"]
```

but I need:

```
["Joe, Doe", "Author", "Title", "Mary, Doe"]
```

Comment: Will the full name _always_ be first?

Comment: did you try something?

Comment: @JamesThorpe no, it should maintain the position from the string.

Comment: How will you reliably identify (using code) which part of the string is the full name then?

Comment: @taia Can't you just change whatever is generating this in the first place?

Comment: @SheraliTurdiyev yes I've tried to split by a regex `code/([\w]+), ([\w]+)/g`

Comment: So your string has two full names - will this always be the case? and will they always have that amount of commas between them.  If not then you cannot do what you are after unless you have a library that contains a list of evrery name ever used

Comment: We need more information about this string. Will it always be "FirstName, LastName,Author,Title,FirstName, LastName"? If not, what other ways will the string be formatted? If not, can you give some other examples of strings that are in a different order? Do you have a set list of non-name words that will be in the list (like Author, title)?

Comment: @Pete thanks! This string is a general example; I can't know what would be in the string, I just need to be sure that the full name will never be splitted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = "Joe, Doe,Author,Title,Mary, Doe",
    array = str.split(/,(?!\s)/g);
```

results in: "Joe, Doe" "Author" "Title" "Mary, Doe", assuming that there's always a space in the names and not in the other text.